# How to do sql joins in lambda?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

From time-to-time, I stumble on this problem that I use a subset of lambda joins. Given that I can use any LINQ extensions how should I go about implementing following joins:

[image]

For simplicity sake tables are defined as

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableA] (
    [Key]             INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Value]           NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TableA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Key] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableB] (
    [Key]             INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Value]           NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TableB] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Key] ASC)
);
```

or if you prefer code first

```
public class TableContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<B> TableB { get; set; }
    public DbSet<A> TableA { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<TableB>().Property(o => o.Key).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
        modelBuilder.Entity<TableA>().Property(o => o.Key).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
    }
}

public class B : IKeyValue
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class A : IKeyValue
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public interface IKeyValue
{
    int Key { get; set; }
    string Value { get; set; }
}
```

---

### As my effort

[((A intersect not B) union (A intersect B))](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((A%20intersect%20not%20B)%20union%20(A%20intersect%20B)))

[image]

```
var leftOuterJoin = TableA
  .GroupJoin(
    TableB, 
    a => a.Key,
    b => b.Key,
    (x, y) => new { TableA = x, TableA = y })
  .SelectMany(
    x => x.TableB.DefaultIfEmpty(),
    (x, y) => new { TableA = x.TableA, TableB = y});
```

[(A intersects B)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(A%20intersects%20B))

[image]

```
var innerJoin = TableA
  .Join(
    TableB, 
    a => a.Key,
    b => b.Key,
    (x, y) => x)
```

[(A union B)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(A%20union%20B))

[image]

```
var fullOuterJoin = TableA
  .FullOuterJoin(
    TableB, 
    a => a.Key, 
    b => b.Key, 
    (x, y, Key) => new {x, y})
```

Comment: Well, have you tried *anything* yet? Done any research? Hint: the LINQ `Join` operation is an inner join.

Comment: @JonSkeet I thought about adding my examples, but I thought it would balance how answers are given.

Comment: Well at the moment the question looks very much like "Do my homework for me." I dare say this *isn't* homework, but it's not a good Stack Overflow question.

Comment: You use a combination of Join, Left Join, except, and union in the right order.  Or you can use https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ for most of them if you are working with IEnumerables.

Answer (score 10):

The most important thing for you, is to know how to perform an `INNER JOIN` and an `OUTER JOIN`.

For the *INNER JOIN* you use `JOIN` from LINQ like so:

[image: INNER JOIN]

```
var result = 
    TableA
    .Join(TableB, left => left.Id, right => right.ForeignKeyToTableA, 
       (left, right) => new { TableAColumns = left, TableBColumns = right });
```

The *OUTER JOIN* you already showed in your example.

Now you need to mix what you know, to get the desired results.

For example to perform a *FULL OUTER JOIN* do something like this pseudocode in LINQ:

```
SELECT TableA.*, TableB.* FROM TableA LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB
UNION
SELECT TableA.*, TableB.* FROM TableB LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA
```

[image: FULL OUTER JOIN]

This would be in LINQ as follows:

```
var fullOuterJoin =
            (
                TableA
                .GroupJoin(TableB, 
                    left => left.Id, right => right.ForeignKeyId, 
                    (left, right) => new { TableA = left, TableB = right })
                .SelectMany(p => p.TableB.DefaultIfEmpty(), (x, y) => 
                    new { TableA = x.TableA, TableB = y })
            )
            .Union
            (
                TableB
                .GroupJoin(TableA, 
                    left => left.Id, right => right.ForeignKeyId, 
                    (left, right) => new { TableA = right, TableB = left })
                .SelectMany(p => p.TableA.DefaultIfEmpty(), (x, y) => 
                    new { TableA = y, TableB = x.TableB })
            );
```

The very last example of your image would then be:

[image: FULL OUTER JOIN with nulls]

```
var fullOuterJoinOnlyWithNulls =
            fullOuterJoin
            .Where(p => p.TableA == null || p.TableB == null);
```

A *RIGHT OUTER JOIN* is nothing but a *LEFT OUTER JOIN* where you swap your result columns like this:

[image]

```
var rightOuterJoin =
            (
                TableB
                .GroupJoin(TableA,
                    left => left.Id, right => right.ForeignKeyId,
                    (left, right) => new { TableA = right, TableB = left })
                .SelectMany(p => p.TableA.DefaultIfEmpty(), (x, y) =>
                    new { TableA = y, TableB = x.TableB })
            );
```

Like this you can construct all your example scenarios. Just check the tables for *null* when needed.