# Flat data with SelectMany() like left join

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

Is it possible to use SelectMany() and have it behave like a left join?

I am trying to flatten an Entity Object into a tabular format. The SelectMany() works like a charm so long as there is a child object, but I want to see all of the parent objects regardless of whether it has children or not.

```
public class Folder
{
    [Key]
    public int Folder_Id { get; set; }
    public string Folder_Name { get; set; }
    public int Folder_order { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Module> Modules { get; set; }
}
public class Module
{        
    [Key]
    public int Module_Id { get; set; }
    public int? Folder_Id { get; set; }
    public string ModuleName { get; set; }
    public virtual Folder Folder { get; set; }

}
public static List<Menu> GetMenu()
{
    var Menu = db.Folder.Get();
    var q = from u in Menu
    from m in u.Modules
    select new {folderName = u.Folder_Name, moduleName = m.ModuleName};
    return q;
}
```

I need is:

folderName="ENG",moduleName="req"

folderName="ENG",moduleName="BOM"

folderName="Inbox",moduleName=""

folderName="Help",moduleName=""

folderName="Dashboard",moduleName=""

folderName="Procurement",moduleName="Indent"

Comment: what will be joining condtion ???

Comment: maybe use left join?

Comment: You are looking for a left outer join. See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36882478/how-to-do-sql-joins-in-lambda/36883214#36883214)

Comment: In your SelectMany statement, you can include an extra step if the navigation property is null. In this regard, notice that @Sefe's comment was incorrect - navigation properties are always included via left outer joins.

Comment: What if you replace `u.Modules` with `u.Modules.DefaultIfEmpty`?

Answer (score 0):

When you chose navigation properties over a join, you were indeed following the recommended practice for entity framework. Alas, navigation properties only work for inner joins. So in this case `SelectMany` will not help you. So you have to resort to a join:

```
var q =
    from u in Menu
    join m in Modules on u.Folder_Id equals m.Folder_Id into modules
    from mm in modules.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new {folderName = u.Folder_Name, moduleName = mm?.ModuleName ?? String.Empty};
    return q;
```